# Store the value of Alert Message in Selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

How to store the value of Alert/Confirmation Message in Selenium IDE ??

and please also explain how to click on ok button of alert message

Comment: Read the last 2 paragraphs of the storeAlert documentation.  If you see an alert message, you are stuck.  Selenium has to redefine window.alert for every page that loads in order to intercept the function to automate it.  If the page alerts a message before the page onload event, Selenium has no such opportunity.  (Assuming native window.alert and not a JS widget.)

Answer (score 1):

StoreAlert and StoreConfiramtion

**storeAlert**

```
Returns:
    The message of the most recent JavaScript alert

Retrieves the message of a JavaScript alert generated during the previous action, or fail if there were no alerts.

Getting an alert has the same effect as manually clicking OK. If an alert is generated but you do not consume it with getAlert, the next Selenium action will fail.

Under Selenium, JavaScript alerts will NOT pop up a visible alert dialog.

Selenium does NOT support JavaScript alerts that are generated in a page's onload() event handler. In this case a visible dialog WILL be generated and Selenium will hang until someone manually clicks OK.
```

**storeConfirmation**

```
Returns:
    the message of the most recent JavaScript confirmation dialog

Retrieves the message of a JavaScript confirmation dialog generated during the previous action.

By default, the confirm function will return true, having the same effect as manually clicking OK. This can be changed by prior execution of the chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation command.

If an confirmation is generated but you do not consume it with getConfirmation, the next Selenium action will fail.

NOTE: under Selenium, JavaScript confirmations will NOT pop up a visible dialog.

NOTE: Selenium does NOT support JavaScript confirmations that are generated in a page's onload() event handler. In this case a visible dialog WILL be generated and Selenium will hang until you manually click OK.
```